# Wordpress audio shortcode override metadata

Tags: wordpress, audio, shortcode

I am using this code to overwrite Wordpress audio in the post. Is there a way I could access metadata of the audio like cover artwork, artist, duration?

```
add_filter('wp_audio_shortcode_override', 'my_audio_shortcode_override', 10, 2);

function awp_audio_shortcode_override( $html, $attr ) {

        

        if (isset( $attr['wav']) || isset( $attr['mp3']) || isset( $attr['m4a']) || isset( $attr['ogg']) || isset( $attr['src'])){

            $attr['type'] = 'audio';
            

            return add_player($attr);
            
        }else{
            return "";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [wp_read_audio_metadata()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_read_audio_metadata/).

Getting the duration would look something like this:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
$uploads_dir = ( $uploads['baseurl'] . $uploads['subdir'] );
$file = $uploads_dir . '/example.mp3';
$metadata = wp_read_audio_metadata( $file );
print "Audio is " . $metadata['length'] . ' seconds long';
```

Note that `wp_read_audio_metadata()` expects the file path, not the URL.

Comment: how could I get file path from awp_audio_shortcode_override?